# Record Automated Tests for a Xamarin application running in AWS Device Farm

Tags: xamarin, automated-tests, aws-device-farm

I want to record tests for my Xamarin application that I can run on the AWS Device Farm.  I was hoping to find something like Espresso.  Unfortunately, I can't see how to record anything using Visual Studio.  Is it possible using the free edition?

Answer (score 0):

Like `Espresso` , Recommend you to use `calabash`.

1. The tests can be able to run using a cloud service(to be able to test on devices that not have access to).
2. The testing framework should work for both xamarin android and xamarin ios.

You can refer to follow.
[IOS](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios),
[Android](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android)

Comment: Could you point me to a video that shows how to record a test case for a Xamarin based app?  Do I have to use AppCenter?

Comment: Here is a previous video can be refered to (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liy5k-4-ci8).

Comment: Junior - This is from 2015.  It references Xamarin Studio - a product that no longer exists.  I don't believe this is going to be helpful.

Comment: Just saw this from a 11/27/2018 MS Site....  "After delivering support for the final releases of iOS 11 and Android 8 operating systems, Microsoft will discontinue our contributions to Calabash, the open-source mobile app testing tool. We hope that the community will continue to fully adopt and maintain it. "  I've got to downgrade your recommendation of using Calabash based on this note.

Comment: Yeah , current version not have a video , this may not be recommended .`calabash` is sure not supported later.

Answer (score 0):

Once you record your tests properly using Espresso or Calabash, you can upload your app and tests to device farm and run them on our devices easily. Follow this blog post for more information: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/getting-started-with-android-testing-on-aws-device-farm-using-espresso-part-3-uploading-your-android-application-to-aws-device-farm/

Comment: I'd like to record, but that feature doesn't seem to be available in Visual Studio 2017.